# How to get pdflatex if installation only created pdftex

Tags: pdftex, texlive

(sorry for crossposting - i previously put his in StackOverflow, but was advised to post it here)

For an application i need pdflatex, but on the server i have to use i am not allowed to use the normal package installation system.
Therefore, i have downloaded and compiled ('configure', 'make' and 'make install') the sources from

```
texlive-20160523b-source.tar.xz
```

However, this installation has only produced a 'pdftex' but no 'pdflatex'.

When i call this newly installed pdftex i get

```
$ texlive_install/texk/web2c/pdftex ~/Questions_2016F_0.tex 
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /kunden/300419_8021/web/4058971/A4058971/texlive_install/texk/web2c: (*many more paths*)
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdftex)

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdftex.fmt
mktexfmt: No such file or directory
I can't find the format file `pdftex.fmt'!
```

Shouldn't texmf.cnf, mktexfmt and pdftex.fmt (and pdflatex.fmt) have been installed wit texlive?

How can i get a working pdftex, and eventually a working pdflatex?

Comment: pdflatex and pdftex are the same binary (one is a symlink to the other in systems that support links) but impossible to say  why mktexfmt isn't working for you  But you shouldn't have to compile  it from source just install texlive from tug it does not need admin permissions and can be installed anywhere that you have write access.

Comment: when i use the installer from tug,  the binaries are not executable, even though they exist and have rwxr-x---. I the downloaded the sources again and built them again. This time i got a pdflatex, but still get a message about  missing pdflatex.fmt

Comment: they work for thousands of other people... what platform are you using,  linux64?

Comment: It's a webhosting server. uname -a returns `Linux m25s20-6-39db.ispgateway.de 3.14.51-grsec-x86_64 #9 SMP Tue Mar 1 11:14:28 CET 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v3 @ 2.60GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Comment: Since my hand-made installation has a callable pdflatex - is there a way to get a pdflatex.fmt? And if yes where should it be put so pdftex can find it?